# StoreKit purchase fails yet 'your purchase was successful" alert is displayed

Tags: ios, storekit

I'm developing an app that allows users to subscribe to different levels of service. Occasionally, the purchases will fail (in particular upgrading followed by downgrading), yet the *"You're all set. Your purchase was successful."* StoreKit alert is displayed.

Is anyone familiar with this behavior? Is it just a bug with the sandbox environment?

Comment: Which type of subscription you are using?